# Breeding the Yeti

Tags: zoo-tycoon

In Zoo Tycoon you can get the Yeti as a downloadable creature for your zoo. They cost 10,000 each and are very difficult to maintain. The question is, what are the requirements for getting these animals to breed. When they do, what is the price for selling them?

Comment: Well, when a mommy yeti and a daddy yeti love each other very much...

Comment: @Studoku I have one male and 2 females.........

Comment: You need them super happy all the time.